# Google Cloud Functions Credentials for Local Development

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, service-accounts

I have a google cloud function. Within this function, I want to write files to GCS (google cloud storage), then get a signed URL of the file that is written to GCS and send that URL to the caller.

For local development, I run the functions locally using the functions-framework command:
`functions-framework --source=.build/ --target=http-function --port 8082`

When I want to write to GCS or get the signed URL, the cloud functions framework just tries to get the credentials from the signed-in gcloud CLI user. However, I want to point it to read the credentials from a service account. For all other gcloud development purposes, we have put the service account information in a local creds.json file and point the gcloud to read from that file.

Is there any way I can achieve this for functions? Meaning that when I start the functions locally (using functions-framework), I point it to the creds.json file to read the credentials from there?

Comment: What happens if you `export APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json` before running `functions-framework`?

Comment: I'm not famliar with `functions-framework` but a quick Google suggests that `functions-framework` as a CLI is only used by Python ([link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks#functions-local-ff-run-python)). All Google's SDKs e.g. for GCS make use of Application Default Credentails which you should be using instead of explicilty pathing to a key. If this is true for `functions-framework` (as I suspect), then exporting the variable should work.

Comment: @DazWilkin, you can't recommend to use a service account key file. It's not a good practice and 90% of the time, you can do without. The command `gcloud auth application-default login` is a better recommendation in that case. Especially for testing the signed URL because with that local credential as well as Cloud Functions credential (through metadata server), the private key isn't present and the signed URL must be called in a specific manner (provide token and the service account on behalf you sign the URL)

Comment: @guillaume_blaquiere When running off-GCP, you have fewer choices. Using `gcloud auth application-default login` creates Application Default Credentials too, these have all the powers of the user's account.and are persisted as a key called `{HOME}/.config/gcloud/application-default_credentials`.. What is your proposal?

Comment: It would be great for the community if you could provide any feedback that could verify if the answer composed from the discussion helped?

Comment: Also adding more information to try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

All Google's SDKs, e.g., for GCS, make use of Application Default Credentials which you should be using instead of explicitly pathing to a key. If this is true for functions-framework, then exporting the variable should work.

The command [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) is a better recommendation in that case, especially for testing the signed URL, because with that local credential as well as the Cloud Functions credential (through metadata server), the private key isn't present, and the signed URL must be called in a specific manner (provide token and the service account to be able to sign the URL).
Using `gcloud auth application-default login` creates Application Default Credentials, which have all the powers of the user's account and are persisted as a key called `{HOME}/.config/gcloud/application-default_credentials`.

Answer (score 1):

## Cloud Function Local Development Authentication

This is what I'm doing for local development of a google cloud function using Nodejs that is triggered by a pub/sub event. This function reads a file from a google cloud storage. This uses the [Functions Framework Nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs)

### TL;DR;

```bash
# shell A
gcloud auth application-default login

npm start
```

pub/sub event message

```bash
# shell B
curl -d "@mockPubSub.json" \                                                                                
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  http://localhost:8080
```

### Greater Details

1. Cloud Function with Functions Framework

Docs: [Functions Framework Nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs)

`package.json`

note the `--target` and `--signature-type`

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx functions-framework --target=helloPubSub --signature-type=http"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/debug-agent": "^7.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.1.2"
  }
...
}
```

2. sample nodejs cloud function that [downloads file into memory](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/samples/downloadIntoMemory.js)

```js
/* modified from the sample
index.js
*/

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

function log(message, severity = 'DEBUG', payload) {
  // Structured logging
  // https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_structured_logs

  if (!!payload) {
    // If payload is an Error, get the stack trace.
    if (payload instanceof Error && !!payload.stack) {
      if (!!message ) {
         message = message + '\n' + payload.stack;
      } else {
         message = payload.stack;
      }
    }
  }
  const logEntry = {
    message: message,
    severity: severity,
    payload : payload
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(logEntry));
}

function getConfigFile(payload){
  console.log("Get Config File from GCS")
  const bucketName = 'some-bucket-in-a-project';
  const fileName = 'config.json';

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function downloadIntoMemory() {
    // Downloads the file into a buffer in memory.
    const contents = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download();

    console.log(
      `Contents of gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} are ${contents.toString()}.`
    );
  }

  downloadIntoMemory().catch(console.error);
}


exports.helloPubSub = async (pubSubEvent, context) => {
  /*
  Read payload from the event and log the exception in App project if the payload cannot be parsed
  */
 try {
    const payload = Buffer.from(pubSubEvent.body.message.data, 'base64').toString()
    const pubSubEventObj = JSON.parse(payload) ;
    console.log("name: ", pubSubEventObj.name);

    getConfigFile(pubSubEventObj)

  } catch (err) {
    log('failed to process payload: + payload \n' , 'ERROR', err);
  }

};
```

3. Mock Message for Pub/Sub Event

[blog reference](https://medium.com/@granttimmerman/test-pub-sub-with-the-functions-framework-and-pub-sub-emulator-a2dc39196603), but I'm not using the emulator

`myJson.json`

```json
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

4. encode for Pub/sub message ( *likely there's a better way* )

```bash
cat myJson.json | grep -v % | base64
```

5. take that output and put it into value for the **data** key:

`mockPubSub.json`

```json
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "greeting": "Hello from the Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator!"
    },
    "data": "< put the output of the base64 from above here >",
    "messageId": "136969346945"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

6. Follow steps from the **TL;DR:** above.

#### Disclaimers

- `gcloud auth application-default login` uses the permissions of the user who executes the command. So remember, in production, the service account the cloud function uses will need to read from the storage bucket.
- while scrubbing this (i.e. renaming bits) and copying it over, I may have messed it up. Sorry if that is true.
- this is all contrived if you are curious, my design is to take a message from a cloud scheduler that includes relevant details about what to read from the config.
- this article explains a way to [hot-reload the cloud function](https://medium.com/google-cloud/hot-reload-node-cloud-functions-64ffdb095a00)
- It remains unclear why I'm using ``-signature-type=http` to mock message, but for now, I am.